# How can I set Z up coordinate system in three.js?

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, three.js, webvr

In three.js Y axis represent up and down and Z axis represent forward and backward. But I want Z axis to represent up and down and Y axis to forward and backward. Here is a image showing what I want:

[image]

I want to change the entire coordinate system in such a way that, if I rotate a mesh around y axis, it follows the new coordinate system not the traditional one.

Now, I have searched stack overflow and found this link:

1. [Three.JS rotate projection so that the y axis becomes the z-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272297/three-js-rotate-projection-so-that-the-y-axis-becomes-the-z-axis) .
   It doesn't work.
2. [THREEJS: Matrix from Z-Up Coordinate System to Y-Up Coordinate System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571364/threejs-matrix-from-z-up-coordinate-system-to-y-up-coordinate-system). This method just change the object or mesh y and z vertices but if I rotate it around y axis it rotates around the traditional y axis. I have to apply the matrix to the rotation matrix also to make it rotate like the new coordinate system.
3. [Changing a matrix from right-handed to left-handed coordinate system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263072/changing-a-matrix-from-right-handed-to-left-handed-coordinate-system)
4. [Reorienting axes in three.js fails when webpage is refreshed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079679/reorienting-axes-in-three-js-fails-when-webpage-is-refreshed). This doesn't work also.

Is there any way I can make three.js to work like Z up coordinate system?

Comment: Putting aside the fact that three.js uses the right handed system, you could try scaling your scene in negative z, and flipping the render order of faces.

Comment: You should accept the answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can set the up vector of the camera using

```
camera.up.set(0,0,1);
```

Then, it will work like you expect.

Comment: IT is better to completely chagne the coordinate system as said in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58554774/5202815

Answer (score 23):

The answer above works in simple case, but if you wish for example to use the editor, you better set before doing anything

```
THREE.Object3D.DefaultUp = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);
```

So any new object will also use this convention. 
Using the previous answer, I struggled in the editor on on all the implications around the controls, saving the objects etc...

Please note that if you use a grid you still have to rotate it so that it covers XY plane instead of XZ

```
var grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 30, 30, 0x444444, 0x888888 );
grid.rotateX(Math.PI / 2);
```

Comment: Even with your extra code, some things, e.g. [`BoxGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/BoxGeometry), seem like they hard-code 'up' (e.g. `height`) as the y-axis.

Comment: Anyone know the equivalent code for `react-three-fiber`?

Answer (score 0):

### For react-three-fiber

Use `THREE.Object3D.DEFAULT_UP = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1)`

Barebone code looks like this:

```js
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import * as THREE from "three";

export default function App() {
    THREE.Object3D.DEFAULT_UP = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);

    return (
        <Canvas>
            {/* Other components here */}
        </Canvas>
    );
}
```